# How to easily manage unique values for a column in Excel/Google sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, applescript, tags

This feature is very common in web application but I could not find a similar solution in Excel.

I manually enter metadata for different publication. One column is the publisher.

I want to have a drop down sorted list for this column with all the previous values already entered. When I type some text, I will get all the available items that contain it and I will be able to choose one.

If I don't find an entry, I want to easily add this publisher to the list and it will be available for other entries.

Bonus points () for a solution that will do this, but for adding multiple unique values in a column, separated with a comma (multiple tags).

Thanks!

edit - adding an example

[image]

Column B is the name of the author. This list comes from column D.

Now I have a new author - Abbott Hailey.

I want to enter the new name without moving away from B2 and it will be also added to the list in column D.

Comment: Multi-selection is not difficult, it has been done many times. For example [**this tutorial**](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/)(you will need to replace the end of the range with a relative address, in this case `$A$2:$A$6` with `$A$2:$A6`). There is a problem: if you enter a multi-select in a cell, then this long string becomes another item in the list for future selections.

Comment: @Hanan Cohen  ,, your question is not clear to me,,, please [edit] the post & share some sample data with us !

Comment: @RajeshSinha - thanks. I edited my question and added an example.

Comment: @HananCohen ,, okay for the issue the Drop Down doesn't works,, what you have to do is use COMBO BOX.  Use Developer TAB,, Design then From **Active X** list , select Combobox. Get it's Property,,, use **Linkcell** & **ListFillRange** as required then, find **MatchEntry** , and select option **0 - fm MatchEntryFirstLette** .  Now if U insert any alphabet it get ALL match with it ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I paid a programmer in Fiverr to do it for me and here is his working code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (e.value.toString().trim() == '')
    return
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (range.getNumColumns() == 1 && range.getNumRows() == 1 && range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var Avals = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
    var list = sheet.getRange("D2:D" + Alast).getValues();
    list = [].concat(...list);
    if (list.indexOf(e.value) == -1) {
      list.push(e.value);
      list.sort()
      list = list.map(function (item) {
        return [item]
      })
      console.log(list)
      sheet.getRange("D2:D" + (list.length + 1)).setValues(list)
    }
  }
}
```